# sap.ui.unified.Calendar Issue in Different Logon Language

Tags: sapui5

[sap.ui.unified.Calendar](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.ui.unified.sample.CalendarSingleDaySelection/preview) is different based on different language:

- For English, the calendar starts with Sunday as **first day of week**
- For German, it starts with Monday.

How to make it consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control `sap.ui.unified.Calendar` has the property [`firstDayOfWeek`](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.ui.unified.Calendar/methods/setFirstDayOfWeek):

> If set, the first day of the displayed week is this day. Valid values are 0 to 6. If not a valid value is set, the default of the used locale is used.

- The default value is `-1` meaning the first day of week is based on [user's **preferred** language / locale](https://ui5.sap.com/index_v1.html#docs/guide/91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html#loio91f21f176f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070__section_6CAF7D95C27C487CB201CE83345AC370).
- `0` is *Sunday*.
- `1` is *Monday*.